# How to convert a data frame or matrix to Javascript array in R?

Tags: javascript, arrays, r, dataframe

Suppose I have a data frame like:

```
 df = data.frame(a=c(1,2,3),b=c(40,50,60),c=c(100,200,300))
```

How could I convert it to a string containing Javascript array like:

```
 [[1, 2, 3], [40, 50, 60], [100, 200, 300]]
```

Answer (score 2):

Without regex:

```
paste0("var myarray = [",paste0("[", apply(df, 2, function(x) paste0(x,"",collapse = ", ")),"]",collapse=", "),"];")
#[1] "var myarray = [[1, 2, 3], [40, 50, 60], [100, 200, 300]];"
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```
jsstring = paste("var myarray = [",
    gsub('\\(','[',
         gsub('\\)',']',
              gsub('c','',toString(df)))), "];")
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
//first convert dataframe to string (I have no IDEA)
var myString = "a=c(1,2,3),b=c(40,50,60),c=c(100,200,300)";

var newString = myString.replace(new RegExp("\\(", "g") ,"~~~").replace(new RegExp("\\)", "g"),"~~~" );

var result = newString.split('~~~').filter(function(num, index){ if( index % 2 !== 0 ) return num;}).map(function(item) { var arr = []; arr.push(item); return arr;})


 console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use jsonlite package.
Just 2 lines of code.

```
library(jsonlite)

toJSON(df,dataframe = "values")
```

I think this should work.